# type safe mustache templates

Tags: typescript, templates, visual-studio-code, mustache

Is there a solution where you could do the following?:

my-template.mustache

```
Hello {{name}}!
```

index.ts

```
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as Mustache from 'mustache';

export interface Person {
    name: string;
}

const hash: Person = {
    name: 'Jon'
};

const template = readFileSync('my-template.mustache', 'utf-8');

// somehow let the IDE know the hash type
const result = Mustache.render(template, hash);

writeFileSync('my-template.html', result, 'utf-8');
```

Then if you did:

my-template.mustache

```
Hello {{name}}, {{age}} <!-- red squiggles under age -->
```

So `age` is not a property of type **Person** and the hash type is **Person** so you get red squiggles under `age`. Preferably a mechanism that would work in in Visual Studio Code.

Update:
To be clear `Hello {{name}}, {{age}} <!-- red squiggles under age -->` is what I'm trying to accomplish, not the problem I'm having.

Comment: This library takes a best pass at extracting mustache types in line with other responses: https://github.com/rjz/ts-mustache

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this; however, there are some complex ones. The easiest of them that came to my head is to create a tool that will compile your `*.mustache` templates into typescript modules, and then you just import those modules as regular typescript files instead of `fs.readFileSync`ing them. Here's an example of what compilation result may look like for your template with age:

```js
import * as Mustache from 'mustache';

const template = 'Hello {{name}}, {{age}} <!-- red squiggles under age -->';
export interface TemplateParams {
    name: string;
    age: string;
}
export default function render(params: TemplateParams): string {
    return Mustache.render(template, params);
}
```

This tool also will need to be inserted into your scripts that you use to build your app and incrementally build in watch mode.

Answer (score 0):

As [Nikita mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67489693/3934374), there isn't any tooling to accomplish this with Mustache and you would need to write a compiler. If you're willing to move away from mustache, you could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

I wrote [embedded-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/embedded-typescript) which uses a compiler to generate type safe templates with an [ejs](https://ejs.co/) inspired syntax. It's open source, so you could use the code as a basis to build something similar for a mustache inspired syntax.

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to declare a type instead of using an interface. Type declaration functions a bit as Traits. In the following it allows you to map any JS Object into a type with new properties, but it will fail if you try to use the wrong type for the given property.

```
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as Mustache from 'mustache';

export interface PersonWithName {
    name: string;
}

export declare type Person = PersonWithName | any;

const hash: Person = {
    name: 'Jon'
};

const hashWithAge: Person = {
    name: 'Jon',
    age: 10,
    newAge: 20
};

const template = readFileSync('my-template.mustache', 'utf-8');
```

Comment: The person is just an example. The "red squiggles under age" is what I'm trying to accomplish (type safety), not the problem I'm having.